# UI Components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am currently developing an angular 4 app. I want to know what is the best  UI components library to use.I found many in the official website (https://angular.io/resources in UI Components part), but I have no idea which is the best one?

Comment: Go for https://material.angular.io

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best" UI library to use. Angular Material (https://material.angular.io) is also made by Google, but you're not restricted to their style. Bootstrap and Foundation are also popular UI frameworks.

In my experience, Material's styling isn't as easily configurable as other frameworks, so if you're deviating significantly, it may be worth looking around.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you thought it is beta https://github.com/angular/material2 for the following advantages:

- Mantained by google developers: (good support for bugs and quality )
- Component modules: you can create a separate NgModule that imports all 
  of the Angular Material components that you will use in your application.
- Theming: A theme is the set of colors that will be applied to the Angular Material components. If you need to customnize your app angular material is great

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience I recommend using [NG-Zorro Angular UI library](https://ng.ant.design/docs/introduce/en) that contains a set of high-quality components and demos for building rich, interactive user interfaces. If you need further information about NG-Zorro you could check this article about [NG-Zorro](https://www.techknowledger.com/ng-zorro-angular-ui-library/) which contains a clear comparison Pros and Cons.